# HTML hyperlink <a href="#..."></a> link showing the id section above instead of the original one in mobile view

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have hosted my web page in GitHub and the mobile version My HTML hyperlinks  is showing the results some pixels above the original starting of the id division. it is showing the section above due to this 'effect'! I don't know why this is happening only in the mobile version and not in the desktop version of the website.

My code in the HTML page is :

```
   <nav>
       <div class="line">
           <div class="s-12 l-2">
               <p class="logo"><strong style="float:left;"><img src="img/top_icon.png"/></strong></p>
           </div>
           <div class="top-nav s-12 l-10">

               <ul class="right">
                   <li class="active-item"><a href="#carousel">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#top-videos">Top Videos</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#about-us">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#our-work">Works</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#shopping">Shopping</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   </nav>
```

and here is the CSS I think the mistake should be in :

```
nav {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:#152732;
}
.line::after, nav::after, .center::after, .box::after, .margin::after, .margin2x::after, .grid.full::after {
  clear:both;
  content: ".";
  display:block;
  height:0;
  line-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.grid.margin::after, .grid.margin2x::after {
  content: "";
  display:none;
}
.nav-text:after,.nav-text:before,.nav-text span {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:3px;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:3px;
  margin:6px auto;
  width: 30px;
  transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.show-menu .nav-text:before {
  transform:translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform:translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
}
.show-menu .nav-text:after {
  transform:translateY(-9px) rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-9px) rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-9px) rotate(-135deg);
}
.show-menu .nav-text span {
  transform:scale(0);
  -moz-transform:scale(0);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0);  
}
.top-nav ul {padding:0;}
.top-nav ul ul {
  position:absolute;
  background:#152732;
}
.top-nav li {
  float:left;
  list-style:none outside none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.top-nav li a {
  color:#fff; 
  display:block;
  font-size:1rem;
  padding:1.25rem; 
}
.top-nav li ul li a {
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #152732;
  min-width:100%;
  padding:0.625rem;
}
.top-nav li a:hover, .aside-nav li a:hover {background:#2b4c61;}
.top-nav li ul {display:none;}
.top-nav li ul li,.top-nav li ul li ul li {
  float:none;
  list-style:none outside none;
  min-width:100%;
  padding:0;
}
```

If you know the answer please tell me. Thankyou in advance :)